# How to add custom list view's number of clicks to custom action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a custom list view and custom action bar (Image Button,text view). When I click on custom list view then number of click add to custom action bar text view.

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.adapter.ListAdapterAddItems;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class DetaisRESTActivity extends Activity {
    String valueid,valueid1,valuename;

   public int count=0;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    public int listViewClickCounter=0;

    ListAdapterAddItems adapter;

    String restaurantmenuname,rastaurantname;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
    public static String RASTAURANTNAMEDETAILS = "RestaurantPizzaItemName";
    public static String RASTAURANTRUPPEES = "RestaurantPizzaItemPrice";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detais_rest);
     //   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.titlebar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
       TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView123456789);
        Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this,listViewClickCounter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mTitleTextView.setText(listViewClickCounter);

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,QuentityActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenuname");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenunameid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("idsrestaurantMenuId5");

        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetaisRESTActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            //  Log.i("123",value1);
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://firstchoicefood.in/fcfapiphpexpert/phpexpert_restaurantMenuItem.php?r=" + URLEncoder.encode(valuename) + "&resid=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid1) + "&RestaurantCategoryID=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid) + "");

            try {

                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenItems");
                Log.i("1234",""+jsonarray);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                     ListModel sched = new ListModel();
                    sched.setProductName(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemName"));
                    sched.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemPrice"));

                    arraylist.add(sched);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
     final ListView   listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdetails);

            adapter = new ListAdapterAddItems();

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                {

                    // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                    ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons: " + p.getCount());
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());

                    count++;
                    String countString=String.valueOf(count);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Item " + (position + 1),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();

                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            countString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    class ListAdapterAddItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel>
    {
        ListAdapterAddItems(){
            super(DetaisRESTActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
            //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView restaurantname = null;
        public TextView ruppees = null;


        ViewHolder(View row) {
            restaurantname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamedetailsrestaurant);
            ruppees = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurant);

        }

        // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
        void populateFrom(ListModel r) {
            restaurantname.setText(r.getProductName());
            ruppees.setText(r.getPrice());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detais_rest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific and tell us what problem you are facing instead of providing the whole code. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and remove all the clutter from your source code that is not necessary and explain in detail what you have tried so far and where exactly you got stuck.

Comment: @sshashank124 when i was click on custom list view,it generate the number of click of list view(count). My problem is number of click does not display on custom action bar text view...help me

Comment: mTitleTextVietw is your custom textview which you want to update right ?

Comment: @pratz9999 yes mTitleTextVietw is my  custom action bar textview

Comment: Can you tell me where are you calculating your final result which you want to display

Comment: It is my final result,i wanna display on                                                  Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this,listViewClickCounter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mTitleTextView.setText(listViewClickCounter);                It my mistake        listViewClickCounter=countString

Comment: you tried calling your method before setting in mTitleTextVietw ? because it is running in oncreate before method is call

Comment: listViewClickCounter is assigned in oncreate ..  you should get the values first before setting the text

Comment: @pratz9999 it is action bar its always assigned in On create() method.

Comment: can u tell me how i will create action bar outside of on create()?

Comment: do two things.. 1) put on click listener in on create. 2) set text mtextview after calling  new DownloadJSON().execute(); try this and let me know

Comment: @pratz9999 ok,i try it and thnaks Sir

Comment: When i was try it ...activity unfortunately closed @pratz9999

Comment: can you tell me the error it is caused by

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.DetaisRESTActivity.onCreate(DetaisRESTActivity.java:86)        86 line number is listview ,When i was used it inside oncreate() method

Comment: null pointer ok .. Edit the code you have provided if possible

Comment: can u change in my code?

Comment: ok.. Let me try .. Or move this discussion to chat

Comment: I cannot chat write now  i have less reputation

Comment: Activity unfortunately closed